# Warehouse Management for Assets

Tags: api

I'm looking for software that does all the things normally associated with a warehousing application, stock movements, reconciliation, stock counts. Ideally with a sales function that tracks returns; crucially though, it must work for assets.

To be specific, each item will have individual properties (not limited to serial number) that will be added after receiving - this is where normal stock systems fall down.

Must have handheld capabilities for warehouse workers, ideally with an API or self hosted on a Microsoft Stack so we can integrate with our ERP.

There seems to be nothing out there

P.S I've added API as a tag since there are no suitable ones and cannot add them yet

Comment: Every WMS that I have been involved with has been bespoke.  You may have trouble finding something off the shelf.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've found and where I think we'll end up. I'm seeing a couple of companies re a bespoke solution, but would prefer off the shelf for support and regular updates.